# How to update WebKit in Coda 2?

Tags: macos, webkit, coda

Coda 2 have a Web Inspector feature, but it's old WebKit Web Inspector. I want to update it. How I can do it? Download fresh **WebKit.app** and replace some folder in **Coda 2.app** with some folder from WebKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007825/using-webkit-framework-from-webkit-nightly-in-cocoa-app), though please note you can expect to run into bugs if you do this.