# how embed specific version of webkit in app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I don't know if it's possible, but I want to embed in my application a specific version of webkit.

I can use the default version of webkit adding it as framework in xcode, but in this case, when the app goes running in another computer, it will use the webkit (and maybe old) version installed in that computer.

In fact, doing the usually use of webkit framework in xcode will not include the webkit in app at all, just a link to the webkit version installed in the OS.

Comment: Duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007825/using-webkit-framework-from-webkit-nightly-in-cocoa-app